# How to add HTML text field with value from select list via Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have select list like this:

```js
$.fn.optionTest = function(opts) {
    var option = $.extend({}, $.fn.optionTest.defaults, opts);
    $(this).change(function() {
        option.holderObject = $(this);
        if (option.clearOnChange) {
            $(option.actionId).empty();
        }
        var val = $(this).val();
        if ($.fn.optionTest.isArray(val)) {
            $.fn.optionTest.parseArray(val, option);
        } else {
            var label = $(this).children("option:selected").eq(0).text();
            $.fn.optionTest.parseContent(val, option, label);
        }
        $('.' + option.removeLinkOptions.class).click(function(event) {
            $.fn.optionTest.removeRow(this, option);
            event.preventDefault();
        });

        $("[type=date]").datepicker({
            monthNamesShort: $.datepicker.regional["en"].monthNames,
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
   yearRange: "-116:+10",
        });
        return this;
    });
};
$.fn.optionTest.isArray = function(val) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(val) === '[object Array]';
};
$.fn.optionTest.defaults = {
    clearOnChange: false,
    actionId: '#action',
    indexOptions: {
        class: 'field-style field-split25 align-left'
    },
    rowOptions: {        
        class: 'certificates',
  type: 'text',
        name: 'CertificateType[]',
        tag: 'ul'
    },
    CertNoOptions: {
        
        name: 'CertNo[]',
        type: 'text',
        placeholder: 'Cert No.',
        size: 20,
        class: 'field-style field-split25 align-left'
    },
    PlaceofIssueOptions: {        
        name: 'PlaceofIssueCert[]',
        type: 'text',
        placeholder: 'Place of Issue',
        size: 20,
        class: 'field-style field-split25 align-left'
    },
    fromOptions: {        
        name: 'FromCert[]',
        type: 'date',
        placeholder: 'Date of Issue',
        size: 20,
        class: 'field-style field-split25 align-left'
    },
    toOptions: {        
        name: 'ToCert[]',
        type: 'date',
        placeholder: 'Date of Expire',
        size: 20,
        class: 'field-style field-split25 align-left'
    },
    labelOptions: {
        class: 'field-style field-split25 align-left',
  type: 'text'
    },
    removeLinkOptions: {
        class: 'removeRow',
        href: 'javascript:;'
    }
};
$.fn.optionTest.parseArray = function(vals, options) {
    var selectedOptions = options.holderObject.children("option:selected");
    console.log(selectedOptions.eq(0).html());
    $.each(vals, function(key, val) {
        $.fn.optionTest.parseContent(val, options, selectedOptions.eq(key).text());
    });
};
$.fn.optionTest.removeRow = function(elem, options) {
    var row = $(elem).closest(".certificates");
    row.remove();
    $.fn.optionTest.updateRowIndex(options);
};

$.fn.optionTest.updateRowIndex = function(options) {
    $("." + options.rowOptions.class).each(function(key, value) {
        var index = key + 1;
        $(value).attr('rowdataid', index);
        $(value).children("." + options.indexOptions.class).html(index);
    });
};

$.fn.optionTest.createColumn = function(content) {
    var li = $('<li>');
    return li.append(content);
}
$.fn.optionTest.parseContent = function(val, options, label) {

    var index = $('.' + options.rowOptions.class).length + 1;


    var rowData = $.extend({}, options.rowOptions);
    var indexData = $.extend({}, options.indexOptions);

    rowData.rowDataId = index;


    var CertNoData = $.extend({}, options.CertNoOptions);
    CertNoData.name = CertNoData.name;

    var PlaceofIssueData = $.extend({}, options.PlaceofIssueOptions);
    PlaceofIssueData.name = PlaceofIssueData.name;

    var DateofIssueData = $.extend({}, options.DateofIssueOptions);
    DateofIssueData.name = DateofIssueData.name;

    var DateofExpireData = $.extend({}, options.DateofExpireOptions);
    DateofExpireData.name = DateofExpireData.name;

    var fromData = $.extend({}, options.fromOptions);
    fromData.name = fromData.name;

    var toData = $.extend({}, options.toOptions);
    toData.name = toData.name;

    var start_by = "<li><ul class='column'><li>";
    var end_by = "</li></ul></li>";

    var labelData = $.extend({}, options.labelOptions);

    if ($('#' + rowData.id).length == 0) {
        var tag = "<" + rowData.tag + ">";
        delete rowData['tag'];
        var row = $(tag, rowData);
        var id = $('<li>', indexData).html(index);
  
     //var label = $('<li>', labelData).html(label);
  
        var label = $.fn.optionTest.createColumn($("<input>", labelData));
        label = $(start_by + $(label).html() + end_by);
  
        var CertNo = $.fn.optionTest.createColumn($("<input>", CertNoData));
        CertNo = $(start_by + $(CertNo).html() + end_by);

        var PlaceofIssue = $.fn.optionTest.createColumn($("<input>", PlaceofIssueData));
        PlaceofIssue = $(start_by + $(PlaceofIssue).html() + end_by);

        var DateofIssue = $.fn.optionTest.createColumn($("<input>", DateofIssueData));
        DateofIssue = $(start_by + $(DateofIssue).html() + end_by);

        var DateofExpire = $.fn.optionTest.createColumn($("<input>", DateofExpireData));
        DateofExpire = $(start_by + $(DateofExpire).html() + end_by);

        var from = $.fn.optionTest.createColumn($("<input>", fromData));
        from = $(start_by + $(from).html() + end_by);

        var to = $.fn.optionTest.createColumn($("<input>", toData));
        to = $(start_by + $(to).html() + end_by);

        var removeRow = $.fn.optionTest.createColumn($("<button>", options.removeLinkOptions).text("X"));
        removeRow = $($(removeRow).html());
       // row.append(label).append(CertNo).append(PlaceofIssue).append(from).append(to).append(removeRow);
  row.append('<input type="hidden" name="RowCertificateType[]" value="' + val + '" />').append(label).append(CertNo).append(PlaceofIssue).append(from).append(to).append(removeRow);

        $(options.actionId).append(row);
    }
};
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#options').optionTest({
        actionId: '.action2',
        clearOnChange: false
    });
});
```

```html
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>    
  
  <fieldset class="fieldset-borders">
        <legend>6. Certificates</legend>
        <ul class="header"> 
          <li>
            <select id='options' name="CertificateType[]" class="field-style div-format align-left">
       <option selected disabled value="0">Select certificates</option>
       <option value="1">Foo</option>
       <option value="2">Bar</option>
       <option value="3">OTHER</option>
            </select>  
          </li>
        </ul>
        <div class="action2" ></div>          
    </fieldset>
```

As you see after selecting any option from list It adding some fields. I need to add text field label with value that selected from options.

As in example I have 3 options:

```
Foo
Bar
OTHER
```

If I select `Foo` It should add fields like:

```
Foo [    ] [    ] [    ] [    ]
```

If I select `Bar` It should add fields like:

```
Bar [    ] [    ] [    ] [    ]
```

If I select `OTHER` It should generate only blank fields without value:

```
[    ] [    ] [    ] [    ] [    ]
```

For now It adding all blank fields for any selected option.

If I use:

`var label = $('<li>', labelData).html(label);`

Instead of:

```
var label = $.fn.optionTest.createColumn($("<input>", labelData));
label = $(start_by + $(label).html() + end_by);
```

It adding label field with value, but not editable, It's not text field and after adding `OTHER` It can't be changed.

Have you ideas how can I achieve correct syntax with `If`? Something like:

```
If (option selected = 'OTHER') {

   var label = $.fn.optionTest.createColumn($("<input>", labelData));
   label = $(start_by + $(label).html() + end_by);

}
else {
   var label = $('<li>', labelData).html(label);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot be certain that I understand your question, but I *think* what you want is for the selected label to display as the value in the first input field, unless the selected label is "OTHER", in which case the field should have no value property.

If this is correct, we could achieve this by extending our `labelData` object:

```
var labelData = $.extend({}, options.labelOptions, {
    value: ((label === 'OTHER') ? '' : label)
});
```